# Верстка блок-схем, инфоблоков

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, canvas, блок-схема

Добрый день. Может кто-нибудь знает отличный способ верстки данных схем, да и вообще подобных. Кроме просто все целиком в картинку вырезать и с использованием `js` и `canvas`. Может есть кто делает подобное как-то по-другому?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На svg https://d3js.org/